# Video Play/Pause on hover only working on one container

Tags: javascript

I have four videos on a page and the below code works, but only when hovering over the first one. When hovering over the other three nothing happens?

All are within the same divs with the same class names.

```
  let clip = document.querySelector(".workVideo > div > div > div > video")
  clip.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
        clip.play();
  })
  clip.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        clip.pause();
  })
```

Comment: because you only select one of them 
You have to use `document.querySelectorAll(".workVideo > div > div > div > video") and then map on this array and then add event listener to each one of them

Comment: an upvote would be nice 

Answer (score 0):

```
const clip = document.querySelectorAll(".workVideo > div > div > div > video");

for (let i = 0; i < clip.length; i++) {
    clip[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
        clip[i].play();
    });
    clip[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
        clip[i].pause();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).